# useNavigate is not working with useParams properly

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a page with `localhost:3000/content` URL which is having multiple projects in it and each project is associated with a project id. When I click on any project, it use the project id via `useParams` hook and pass it to the App.js to generate the dynamic route with `localhost:3000/content/${ProjectId}`. Under every project I have few blogs. To create blogs, I am using the `localhost:3000/createblog` URL with query search parameter for project. So the actual like that will be used to create the blog is something like `localhost:3000/createblog?ProjectId=xxxxxx`.

From the createblog page, if I want to go back, using `navigate(-1)` I am able to go easily. But if I want to use **navigate(`/content/${projectId}`)**, then its not working. In the console.log I can see the proper value and the same URL worked only once when actually came from `/content` page to `/content/projectId` page. The projectId is a string value.

Few code snips for the reference:

- All the available routes in App.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
    <Route path="/login" element={<LoginComponent />} />
    <Route path="/forgot-password" element={<ForgetPasswordComponent />} />
    <Route path="/signup" element={<CreateAccountComponent />} />
        
    <Route
      path="/dashboard"
      element={
        <RequireAuth>
          <LandingPage />
        </RequireAuth>
      }
    />
    
    <Route
      path="/content"
      element={
        <RequireAuth>
          <ContentPage />
        </RequireAuth>
      }
    />
    
    <Route
      path="/content/:projectId"
      element={
        <RequireAuth>
          <ProjectPage />
        </RequireAuth>
      }
    />

    <Route
      path="/createblog"
      element={
        <RequireAuth>
          <CreateBlog />
        </RequireAuth>
      }
    />
    
    <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

- ContentPage.jsx

```
{projects.map((sname) => {
  return (
    <div key={sname.projectKeyId}>
      <Link
        to={sname.projectKeyId}
        state={sname.projectTypeName}
        style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "#546e7a" }}
      >
        <DataTreeView
          treeItems={projects}
          skId={sname.projectKeyId}
        />
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
})}
```

- ProjectPage.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useLocation, useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";


const ProjectPage = () => {
  const { projectId } = useParams();
  const [pagesname, setPagesname] = useState([]);
  const [dashboarderror, setDashboarderror] = useState();
  const location = useLocation();
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const pageId = searchParams.get("pageId");

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const authconfig = {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization:
              "Bearer " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user_token")).token,
          },
        };
        const res = await axios.get(
          dashboardURL,
          authconfig
        );
        for (let i = 0; i < res.data.matrixDetails[2].projects.length; i++) {
          if (
            res.data.matrixDetails[2].projects[i].projectTypeName ===
            location.state
          ) {
            setPagesname(res.data.matrixDetails[2].projects[i].pages);
            );
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        setDashboarderror(e);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [location.state]);

  return (
  <Box>
   {pagesname.map((sname) => {
     return (
       <div key={sname.pageKeyId}>
         <Button
           style={{
            textTransform: "none",
            color: "#546e7a",
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            padding: "2px",
          }}
          onClick={() =>
            setSearchParams({ pageId: sname.pageKeyId })
          }
        >
          <DataTreeView
            treeItems={pagesname}
            pgCode={sname.pageKeyId}
          />
        </Button>
      </div>
     {pageId && <PageView pageId={pageId} />}
    </Box>
    );
  })}

    )
}
```

In createblog page, if I will click the cancel button, it should go to the previous page. Here is the code to handle the Cancel button:

```
const handleClick = () => {
    // navigate(-1);                    // this logic is Working
    navigate(`/content/${projectId}`);  // this logic is not working
  };
```

and I am calling the same click function in below button code:

```
<Button
  variant="outlined"
  color="error"
  size="medium"
  onClick={() => handleClick()}
  sx={{
    borderRadius: 10,
    textTransform: "none",
    ":hover": {
      bgcolor: "error",
      color: "error",
      border: "error",
     },
    }}
  >
    Cancel
</Button>
```

The similar issue is happening when I am displaying the blog as well. The blog display code URL is like `localhost:3000/content/projectId?pageId=xxxxxx`. I can display all the pages properly. But if due to some reason the page is getting refreshed, when the URL is in `localhost:3000/content/projectId?pageId=xxxxxx` position, then the page is completely blank but if I will come back to `localhost:3000/content/projectId` page and refresh, everything working as expected.

Comment: Seems like its the 'useParams' that causing the issue. For the page refresh issue, if I am trying to store the value of `projectId` in a `useState` hook and calling it, its not able to load the page during refresh but if I am directly using the 'projectId' as condition to display, its working. Do i need to use any kind of session persistence component ?

Comment: Is `projectId` supposed to be a route path param, or is the path literally `"/content/projectId"` with a search string, e.g. queryString?

Comment: projectId is a route path parameter. That's why if you will check the app.js, you can see the path as "/content/:projectId". Hence if some one will click on the project name from the content page, based on its id the url will be generated and some one can get into the specific project.

Comment: I see. Can you [edit] the post to fix all the paths you are referencing that are the literal string value `"/content/projectId"` so it's overtly clear what exact path values you are working with? Where is the `CreateBlog` component/page rendered? Please clarify what specifically isn't working in the `handleClick` handler with ```navigate(`/content/${projectId}`);```. See [mcve].

Comment: I have updated all the routes. From the CreateBlog component, I am trying to go to other location using **navigate(`/content/${projectId}`)** which is not working. In the actual route, '/content/:projectId' path is working where the value of projectId is a parameter coming from useParams hook.

Comment: Thanks. I don't really see any overt issues with the code you've shared. How is the ```navigate(`/content/${projectId}`);``` not working for you? What is it doing? Is `projectId` defined in the `CreateBlog` component? Can you share a more complete `CreateBlog` code example?

Comment: May be this issue is happening because I am not storing the value of projectId anywhere either in localStorage or sessionStorage. And when we are moving away from this page, its causing issue because either via a page refresh or because of multiple page rendering, the state value is lost ?

Comment: I'm not sure where you are getting `projectId` from in the `CreateBlog` component. Here is a working StackBlitz which I think has all the functionality you have described above: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-skfc4l?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: I am getting the projectId in the ContentPage and generating a link using Link from react router dom which is helping me to navigate to the ProjectPage. I am adding the ConetntPage code and ProjectPage code in the main description again.

Answer (score 0):

Routes were correct. Its the wrong projectName validation condition which was causing the if condition to fail and then it was unable to fetch the pages in that project.

After some debugging, I found that my condition was wrong. After a page url change, the `location.state` was changing which was breaking the if condition.

###### Old code in ProjectPage.jsx

```
for (let i = 0; i < res.data.matrixDetails[2].projects.length; i++) {
  if (
    res.data.matrixDetails[2].projects[i].projectTypeName ===
    location.state
  ) {
    setPagesname(res.data.matrixDetails[2].projects[i].pages);
    );
  }
}
```

When the page was loading for the first time, I used to save a localStorage property `proName`. Hence just get that to validate and it started working.

##### New Code in ProjectPage.jsx

```
for (let i = 0; i < res.data.matrixDetails[2].projects.length; i++) {
  const spName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("proName"));
  if (
    res.data.matrixDetails[2].projects[i].projectTypeName ===
    location.state || proName === res.data.matrixDetails[2].projects[i].projectTypeName
  ) {
    setPagesname(res.data.matrixDetails[2].projects[i].pages);
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad you worked it, although that's not related to the original question